Revoke ERC-20 Smart contract approval
Is it possible to revoke the approval given in ERC-20 smart contract in solidity.

Yes, it is possible to revoke an approval given in an ERC-20 smart contract. In ERC-20, token approvals are managed by the approve function, which allows a token holder to approve a spender to transfer a specified amount of tokens on their behalf.
To revoke the approval, the token holder can simply set the approved amount to zero by calling the approve function again with the spender’s address and an amount of 0.
Here’s how it works:
Example of Revoking Approval
IERC20 token = IERC20(addressOfYourToken);
token.approve(spenderAddress, 0);

Explanation:

addressOfYourToken: The address of the ERC-20 token contract.

spenderAddress: The address of the spender you want to revoke approval from.

0: Setting the approval amount to zero effectively revokes any previous approval.


After this transaction, the spender will no longer have permission to transfer the token holder’s tokens.

Yes its working , Thankyou for this knowledge.

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
